ib_insync RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread
I'm looking to use a pickled object of ib_insync.Stock in Dash App but receiving an error about lack of event loops. 
How to reproduce: Create two files. 1. one to create a pickle of a ib_insync.Stock. 2. Small Dash App that loads this pickle file.
#do_a_save.py
import pickle
from ib_insync import Stock, IB

stock = Stock(symbol="AAPL", exchange='SMART', currency='USD')


with open('stock.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(stock, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

#app.py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import pickle

app = Dash()

app.layout = [
    html.H1(children='Title of Dash App', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    html.Div(children='', id = 'output-container', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    html.Button(children='Load!', id = 'button')
]

@callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks')
)
def load_stock(n_clicks):
    with open('stock.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        stock = pickle.load(f)
    return str(stock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

This issue might involve putting:
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

somewhere as suggested here. Another similar issue is here
FYI the error comes from this line in eventkit module:
File ".../IBenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eventkit/util.py", line 21, in get_event_loop
    return asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()

